# WebPack Config Error w/ Phantom.JS & Pageres (Node Modules)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, phantomjs, webpack

I'm trying to import the node package module known as "pageres" (https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres) which uses Phantom.JS to take a screenshot of webpages defined by the user. I use NPM to install pageres successfully, but upon trying to import the module into my project, it throws the the exceptions of:  "cannot resolve module 'child_process'", "cannot resolve module 'fs'", and "cannot resolve module 'net'". When looking into this problem, I find (https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/998) the work around is to add the following snippet of code to my webpack config file:

```
node: {
  fs: "empty",
  child_process: 'empty',
  net: 'empty'
}
```

The issue is, this DOES clear the errors preventing webpack from compiling my code, but now my application does not render at all.

Is there any workaround available to solve this issue, and can anyone explain why the errors I had earlier with "cannot resolve module 'child_process'" came about ?

Side Notes: I'm using React-Redux-Universal (https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) as my boiler, thus React.JS is handling my view.

Webpack config (located within the Universal-redux config file below):

```
 webpack: {
    /*
    // A list of libraries that do not change frequently between deploys
    // and are best served in the vendor bundle. Optional.
    //
    // Expects: Array
    */
    // vendorLibraries: [],

    /*
     // Webpack configuration cusomtizations. There are more parameters
     // available than specified here. For the full list, see
     // https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html.
     */
    config: {

      /*
       // The Webpack devtool configuration. May affect build times.
       // See https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
       */
      devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-eval-cheap-source-map',

      resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.scss', '.css' ]
      },

      module: {
        loaders: [{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'postcss' }]
      },
      node: {
  fs: "empty",
  child_process: 'empty',
  net: 'empty'
},
```

Universal-redux config file (contains webpack config):

```
/* eslint-disable */
require('dotenv').config({silent: true});
const path = require('path');
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
const sourceRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');

module.exports = {

  /*
   // Express configuration
   */
  server: {
    /*
     // The host to run the Express universal renderer. See src/server.js.
     //
     // Expects: String
     */
    host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',

    /*
     // The port to run Express universal renderer will run on. See src/server.js.
     //
     // Expects: Number
     */
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000

    /*
    // The path at which static assets are served from. If omitted, Express will
    // serve any static assets from your project root 'static' directory.
    // Optional.
    //
    // Expects: String
    */
    // staticPath: projectRoot + '/static',

    /*
    // The path at which a favicon image will be served from using the `serve-favicon`
    // library. If omitted, Express will not serve a favicon. Optional.
    //
    // Expects: String
    */
    // favicon: projectRoot + '/static/favicon.ico',

    /*
    // The maximum age, in milliseconds, for which a static asset will be
    // considered fresh, per the Cache-Control max-age property. If
    // ommitted, defaults to 0. Optional.
    //
    // Expects: Number
    */
    // maxAge: 0
  },

  /*
  // Providers for the root component to assemble. Built in options
  // include 'react-router', 'redux-simple-router', 'redux-async-connect',
  // 'async-props'. Custom root components may accept additional options.
  // Optional. If unspecified will use react-router, react-router-redux,
  // and redux-async-connect.
  //
  // Expects: Array
  */
  // providers: [
  //   'react-router',
  //   'react-router-redux',
  //   'async-props'
  // ],

  /*
   // Globals available to both serverside and clientside rendering.
   // You may also add your own here.
   */
  globals: {

    /*
     // Whether or not to run redux-logger
     //
     // Expects: Boolean
     */
    __LOGGER__: !isProduction,

    /*
     // Whether or not to run redux-devtools
     //
     // Expects: Boolean
     */
    __DEVTOOLS__: !isProduction,

    /*
    // Whether or not to show redux-devtools when page loads.
    //
    // Expects: Boolean
    */
    __DEVTOOLS_IS_VISIBLE__: false
  },

  /*
   // Enable eslint checks per Webpack build. Will not be run
   // on production.
   //
   // Expects: Boolean
   */
  lint: {
    enabled: true,
    config: projectRoot + '/.eslintrc'
  },

  // babelConfig: projectRoot + '/.babelrc',

  /*
   // Enable native desktop notifications for Webpack build events.
   // Will not be run on production.
   //
   // Expects: Boolean
   */
  notifications: false,

  /*
   // Path to a file with customizations for the default
   // webpack-isomorphic-tools configuration. Optional.
   //
   // Expects: String
   */
  // toolsConfigPath: __dirname + '/webpack-isomorphic-tools.config.js',

  /*
   // When eneabled, will output Webpack and Webpack Isomorphic
   // Tools configurations at startup
   //
   // Expects: Boolean
   */
  verbose: true,

  /*
   // The react-router Routes file, Required. Will be added to Webpack aliases.
   */
  routes: sourceRoot + '/routes.js',

  redux: {
    /*
     // The path to the index of your Redux reducers. Required. Will be added
     // to Webpack aliases.
     //
     // Expects: String
     */
    reducers: sourceRoot + '/redux/modules/index.js',

    /*
     // A path to an index of middleware functions. On the serverside, these will
     // be called with the Express request and response. Optional.
     //
     // Expects: String
     */
    middleware: sourceRoot + '/redux/middleware/index.js',
  },

  html: {
    /*
    // A path to a component that provides additional DOM items to be appended
    // to the <head>. Optional.
    //
    // Expects: String
    */
    head: sourceRoot + '/containers/Head/Head.js',

    /*
    // A path to a component that provides the root html shell. It is strongly
    // encouraged to instead use html.head and html.body configurations to
    // provide your own additions, as with this parameter you are responsible
    // for some of the internals of Universal Redux.

    // Be sure that the content includes all of the items inside of the default
    // Head and Body inside of Universal Redux's src/server directory.
    //
    // Expects: String
    */
    // root: sourceRoot + '/containers/Root/Root.js'
  },

  /*
  // Customizations for Webpack configuration. Optional.
  //
  // Expects: Object
  */
  webpack: {
    /*
    // A list of libraries that do not change frequently between deploys
    // and are best served in the vendor bundle. Optional.
    //
    // Expects: Array
    */
    // vendorLibraries: [],

    /*
     // Webpack configuration cusomtizations. There are more parameters
     // available than specified here. For the full list, see
     // https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html.
     */
    config: {

      /*
       // The Webpack devtool configuration. May affect build times.
       // See https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
       */
      devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-eval-cheap-source-map',

      resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.scss', '.css' ]
      },

      module: {
        loaders: [{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'postcss' }]
      },
      node: {
  fs: "empty",
  child_process: 'empty',
  net: 'empty'
},

      postcss: function () {
        return [require('lost'), require('autoprefixer'), require('precss')];
      }
    }
  }
};
/* eslint-enable */
```